# A vertical div with an image pattern on the left and right side

Tags: html, css, border, border-image

So I am trying to make a div like this[image]

But I want it to be vertical because I want the div two kindof have like a paper style look to it: This is the vertical div and I want the random curly edges from above to be on the left and right side of the div
[image]
On the second image you see a blue weired border. I tried to do it with border-image but this doesn't really seem to work because of the random pattern of the border image I'm trying to use.

Css I have right now:

```
bg-section {
border-image: url(../images/test.png) 120 round;
border-right: 40px solid transparent;
border-left: 40px solid transparent;
width: 70%;
margin: auto;
linear-gradient(rgba(199,194,183,0.2), rgba(199,194,183,0));
}
```

This is the border I am trying to use: [image]

Answer (score 1):

You can rotate the image using any tool then use it as background and rely on repeat:

```css
body {
  min-height:800vh;
  margin:0;
  background:
    url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFPJV.png) right repeat-y,
    url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMYNC.png) left repeat-y,
    linear-gradient(green,green) center / calc(100% - 138px) 100% no-repeat;
    
}
```

With the same image you can use pseudo element and rely on transform to rotate the image. You can also easily control the width of the borders:

```css
body {
  min-height:800vh;
  margin:0;
  position:relative;  
  background:linear-gradient(green,green) center / calc(100% - 50px) 100% no-repeat
}
body:before,
body:after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  width:20px; /*Control the width of the border*/
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFPJV.png) center/contain  repeat-y
}
body:before {
  right:10px;
}
body:after {
  left:10px;
  transform:scale(-1,1);
}
```

Comment: Okey so I got it to work with your technic: [link](https://imgur.com/a/GsB58LO)
But I want to fill in the background with a color like the color on the two sides. When I try to do this, this happends: [link](https://imgur.com/a/93UPubd).
I used green just so you can easily see it. I was thinking about only coloring a part of the div but Im not sure on how to do this.

Comment: @RaytjeKn ok check my edit ;) you can use a gradient to create the background color and avoid that issue ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked for me. Now there is one thing I'd like to aks you. I assume you could use this technic on a horizontal div too. So how would I do that? Something like this:
'background:url(../images/links.png) up repeat-x, 
 url(../images/right.png) down repeat-x;'
I tried that but that doesn't seem to work, so I think I forgot something or dit something wrong.

Comment: @RaytjeKn it's not `up`/`down` but `top`\ `bottom` ;) ... so it should be something like `background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFPJV.png) top/contain  repeat-x`